# Sitecore Rocks 3.0.281 fails when opening items

Tags: sitecore-rocks

My Sitecore rocks automatically updated on 8/1 and now opening items throw an error with the following message (see screen shot).  Is there a workaround or something that needs to be reconfigured?

[image: Sitecore Rocks error message dialog]

Comment: What version of Sitecore are you connected to?

Comment: I am also getting same error. I am using Sitecore Rocks 3.0.281 and Sitecore 8.1 Initial version.

Comment: Are you able to run the Sitecore client from the browser?

Comment: Sitecore 8.2.171121 and from the browser functions normal

Comment: I am the Product Manager for Rocks.... we are hearing reports of Rocks broken on 8.x instances. We are investigating and intend to release a fix ASAP.

Comment: Jason and @jitendra-ghanekar and anyone else... could you try installing the VSIX from the build artifacts here and confirm whether it resolves the issue for you?
https://dev.azure.com/sitecore-devex/Sitecore%20Rocks/_build/results?buildId=83

Comment: @techphoria414 - Patch worked for me. Thanks

Comment: The new build works for me as well.

Answer (score 1):

The quick answer is now that this has been resolved in Sitecore Rocks 3.0.283, which should auto-update from the [VS Marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=JakobChristensen.SitecoreRocks) or can be [downloaded on GitHub](https://github.com/Sitecore/Sitecore.Rocks/releases/tag/3.0.283).

The details are that there was an issue in the 3.0.281 release of Sitecore Rocks which caused a `MissingMethodException` in `Sitecore.Diagnostics.Log` when run against Sitecore 8.x. Sitecore Rocks 3.0 is built against Sitecore 9.1, which adds overloads to the `Log` class to discourage incorrect use (passing in an `Exception` without an `owner`). Rocks had such an incorrect use which was not fixed on release, so when executed against Sitecore 8.x, the overload was not available.

You can see the fix in [this commit](https://github.com/Sitecore/Sitecore.Rocks/commit/71697351fa57ef8cfc3ae0e1cbb54d0b8eb1c8ec).